# Improve image quality

Tags: image-processing

I need to improve image quality, from low quality to high hd quality. I am using **OpenCV** libraries. I experimented a lot with GaussianBlur(), Laplacian(), transformation functions, filter functions etc, but all I could succeed is to convert image to hd resolution and keep the same quality. Is it possible to do this? Do I need to implement my own algorithm or is there a way how it's done? I will really appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible. You can't increase the amount of information (detail of resolution). The best you can do is guess how to combine actual information to give the idea of better quality, i.e. some kind of interpolation.

Comment: What qualities do you want to improve? Artifacts? Noise? Aging? Blockiness? This is very wide question, please specify and we might help you..

Comment: The transition between different color regions has to be sharper. So, I guess sharpness.

Comment: "improve image quality" has no absolute meaning. Ask for something more explicit. Also consider that what you see in "The Expert" is pure fiction.

Answer (score 4):

I used this [link](https://www.learnopencv.com/non-photorealistic-rendering-using-opencv-python-c/) for my reference. It has other interesting filters that you can play with.

If you are using C++:

```
detailEnhance(Mat src, Mat dst, float sigma_s=10, float sigma_r=0.15f)
```

If you are using python:

```
dst = cv2.detailEnhance(src, sigma_s=10, sigma_r=0.15)
```

The variable '**sigma_s**' determines how big the neighbourhood of pixels must be to perform filtering.

The variable '**sigma_r**' determines how the different colours within the neighbourhood of pixels will be averaged with each other. Its range is from: 0 - 1. A smaller value means similar colors will be averaged out while different colors remain as they are.

Since you are looking for sharpness in the image, I would suggest you keep the kernel as minimum as possible.

Here is the result I obtained for a sample image:

*1. Original image:*

[image]

*2. Sharpened image for lower `sigma_r` value:*

[image]

*3. Sharpened image for higher `sigma_r` value:*

[image]

Check the above mentioned link for more information.

Comment: You will get errors if you try it with kernel=10 and range=0.5; Just put 10 and 0.5 as positional arguments.

Answer (score 3):

How about applying Super Resolution in OpenCV? A reference article with more details can be found here: https://learnopencv.com/super-resolution-in-opencv/

So basically you will need to have the Python dependency `opencv-contrib-python` installed, together with a working version of `opencv-python`.

There are different techniques for the Super Resolution in OpenCV you can choose from, including EDSR, ESPCN, FSRCNN, and LapSRN. Code examples in both Python and C++ have been included in the tutorial article as well for easy reference.

Answer (score 2):

A correction is needed
dst = cv2.detailEnhance(src, sigma_s=10, sigma_r=0.15)

using kernel will give error.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to kris stern answer,

If you are looking for practical implementation of super resolution using pretrained model in OpenCV, have a look at below notebook also video describing details.

https://github.com/pankajr141/experiments/blob/master/Reasoning/ComputerVision/super_resolution_enhancing_image_quality_using_pretrained_models.ipynb

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrWIYWO4bac&list=UUplf_LWNn0a9ubnKCZ-95YQ&index=4

[image]

Below is a sample code using opencv

```
model_pretrained = cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

# setting up the model initialization
model_pretrained.readModel(filemodel_filepath)
model_pretrained.setModel(modelname, scale)

# prediction or upscaling
img_upscaled = model_pretrained.upsample(img_small)
```